# JavaFX Adding a button to top-right of window

Tags: java, button, javafx

I am designing a GUI in JavaFX and I've added to it a `MenuBar` with different `MenuItem`s. I also want it to be undecorated from the `Windows` default `Close` and `Minimize` buttons, so I've called the methods`initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED)` on the `Stage` object. Now I'm trying to put a close button on the top right of the window so that my user can close the now resulted window, but I can't do so with the `BorderPane`s `setTop()` method, because it falls under the `MenuBar` item.
Is there a way to float or add the button on top of the `MenuBar` ?
Or at least have the `X` button in another menu bar that will be positioned before the current menu bar.

This is how it looks right now with the code I have:
[image]
This is the code I ahve so far in the `start()` method:

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    window = primaryStage;
    window.setTitle("Menu Example");


    MenuBar file = new MenuBar();
    file.setId("file");

    Menu fileMenu = new Menu("File");
    fileMenu.getItems().addAll(
            new MenuItem("New File..."),
            new MenuItem("Open file..."),
            new MenuItem("Save file"));
    fileMenu.setId("#fileMenu");



    Menu editMenu = new Menu("Edit");
    editMenu.getItems().addAll(
            new MenuItem("Undo"),
            new MenuItem("Redo"),
            new MenuItem("Cut"),
            new MenuItem("Copy"),
            new MenuItem("Paste")
    );

    Button closeButton = new Button("X");
    closeButton.setOnAction(event -> {
        Platform.exit();
    });
//        closeButton.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_RIGHT);

    file.getMenus().addAll(
            fileMenu,
            editMenu

    );

    layout = new BorderPane();
    layout.setTop(file);
    layout.setRight(closeButton);

    Scene scene = new Scene(layout, 300, 300);
    scene.getStylesheets().add("Viper.css");
    window.setScene(scene);
//        window.setMaximized(true);
    window.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
    window.show();
}
```

Comment: This is not how the `MenuBar` functions, it's designed for adding menus only, I don't think that you will be able to add a button. And even if you did; it may not function properly. Instead, you can following modern style trends and just add a `quit` option under the `file` menu.

Comment: Is there still a way to float it above it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Place the `Button` and the `MenuBar` next to each other in a `HBox` and make sure the `MenuBar` is the only one of those nodes that grows:

```
HBox hbox = new HBox(file, closeButton);

HBox.setHgrow(file, Priority.ALWAYS);
HBox.setHgrow(closeButton, Priority.NEVER);

layout.setTop(hbox);
//layout.setRight(closeButton);
```

Comment: Thank you, it's amazing. And also thank you for reminding me I can combine layouts.